# Sample mean distribution for Gamma random variables

Tags: central-limit-theorem, gamma-distribution

I am curious as to what the sample mean distribution for a set of iid Gamma random variables is.

I know $\bar{X}$ has a Gamma distribution when $X_1, X_2 ... X_n$ are iid ~ exponential with mean $\theta$ and gamma distributed random variables $X_1 + X_2$ also follow a gamma distribution with parameters $(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2, \theta)$, for $X_1$ ~ $(\alpha_1, \theta)$ and $X_1$ ~ $(\alpha_1, \theta)$, but I can't find any information regarding the distribution of the sample mean for a set of gamma distributed random variables.

As a sidenote, when can we approximate $\bar{X}$ with a normal distribution? Ex: when can we say that the distribution of $\bar{X}$ for $X_1, X_2 ... X_n$ iid ~ exponential$(\theta)$ is approximately normal with mean $\theta$ and variance $\frac{\theta}{n}$, instead of saying it follows a gamma distribution?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can in fact relax the requirement that the sample be identically distributed:  suppose for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, we have $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n_i, \theta),$$ where each $n_i$ is a positive integer and $\theta$ is a common scale parameter.  Then $$S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \operatorname{Gamma}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n n_i, \theta\right).$$  This is because each $X_i$ is the sum of $n_i$ iid exponential variables with mean $\theta$; e.g., $$X_i = Y_{i1} + Y_{i2} + \cdots + Y_{in_i},$$ thus the total sum is $$S = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij}.$$
In fact, we do not even require that the $n_i$ are positive integers; they may be arbitrary positive reals, and the result still holds.  This can be shown by considering the moment-generating function of a gamma distribution.  From here, the sample mean $\bar X = S/n$ is also gamma distributed, with shape $\sum n_i$ and scale $\theta/n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $Z=X/n, f_Z(z)=f_X(nz)|J|=C(nz)^{a-1}e^{-nz/\beta}=C'z^{\alpha-1}e^{-z/(\beta/n)}$. This is a gamma pdf with shape $\alpha$ and scale $\beta/n$.

By repeatedly applying additivity of the shape parameter, $Y=\sum{X_i}\sim Gamma(n\alpha,\beta) $. Divide the sum by sample size gives $Y/n \sim Gamma(n\alpha,\beta/n)$